# UIToolBar tintColor not working for iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have created a `UIToolBar` in my app that is colored blue, and it showed as blue when I was building it as a iOS 6 but now that I have updated the build to iOS 7 its turned white?

This is my code.

```
getProjectListToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, screenHeight+20, 44)];
getProjectListToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:130.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

getProjectListToolBar.translucent = NO;
getProjectListToolBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
getProjectListToolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
getProjectListToolBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
getProjectListToolBar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
[self.view insertSubview:getProjectListToolBar aboveSubview:self.view];
```

How can I get it blue again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set

```
getProjectListToolBar.translucent = NO;
```

In iOS 7 `UITabBar` and `UINavigationBar` has `translucent` property and for both you need to set `translucent = NO` , Its just for your information.

**EDITED**

```
[getProjectListToolBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:130.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Because in iOS 7 you need to set `barTintColor` instead of `tintColor` from [this documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW5)

I tried with your code in my demo project and it worked for me.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code you showed me, is that correct? as It still is not changing to the correct color... I later go on to set some items using **[getProjectListToolBar setItems:buttonsArray  animated:YES];** would that cause the background any color issues?

Answer (score 3):

In ios7 there are 2 properties:

1. tintColor: Will set color of toolbar item
2. barTintColor : will set color of toolbar

Use barTintColor.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove from you code :

```
getProjectListToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0  green:130.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

and add line

```
[getProjectListToolBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:85.0/255.0 green:130.0/255.0 blue:186.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

and also check your 'getProjectListToolBar' frame coordinates